# Understanding how to write code for unit tests

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, unit-testing, testing

I have my service layer which uses Entity Framework 6.  I have tried to mock Entity Framework, without much success (1 step forward, 2 back), but i think the ball has now dropped in my head.  I have never really created code for unit tests before, so it is a bit new.

Am i right in thinking, its all about just writing your code in a few more "testable" functions/actions instead.

So for example, i have my AddAsync method that looks something like this (very basic, keeping it simple)

```
public override async Task<int> AddAsync(FieldGroup t)
{
    // new groups are added to the last position in the location
    var groupCount = await _context.FieldGroups
        .OrderBy(e => e.Position)
        .CountAsync();

    // if there is no groups, set position to 1
    // else if there is set it equal to the last position + 1
    if (groupCount == 0)
    {
        t.Position = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        t.Position = (short)(groupCount + 1);
    }

    return await base.AddAsync(t);
}
```

Basically, when i add my FieldGroup, i need to get the correct position number to insert it and set the Position.

In order to make this more "unit testable", should i just move the code out of the AddAsync function, into another function that accepts a number as the parameter. So something like this

```
public override async Task<int> AddAsync(FieldGroup t)
{
    // new groups are added to the last position in the location
    var groupCount = await _context.FieldGroups
        .Where(e => e.ModuleId == t.ModuleId && e.Location == t.Location)
        .WhereNotDeleted()
        .OrderBy(e => e.Position)
        .CountAsync();

    t.Position = GetNextPositionNumber(groupCount);

    return await base.AddAsync(t);
}

public short GetNextPositionNumber(int groupCount)
{
    // if there is no groups in this location, set position to 1
    // else if there is set it equal to the last position + 1
    if (groupCount == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return (short)(groupCount + 1);
    }
}
```

Now tests can be run on the GetNextPositionNumber method, and i know longer require Entity Framework to get anything.

Now if you do this, obviously i am now testing the GetNextPositionNumber method, and not the AddAsync method, but then testing the AddSync method should be apart of some integration testing later, which will make sure the whole method works, and i could use EF and a testing database to test this.

Is this right, or am i missing the point completely?

If this is wrong, how do you write your tests and mock EF? I seem to hit a wall everytime i solve something.  Like first being able to mock EF using Async, then setting state on an entity, then using the Include keyword to load entities.

Comment: You can definitely do it like that. However, it comes with understanding that you are no longer testing the whole `AddAsync`, method, but only the `GetNextPositionNumber` method.

Comment: Shouldnt then testing the AddSync method, with EF be done with integration testing afterwards?

Comment: Absolutely, it should be tested as part of integration testing. However, there's still no unit test for it (which may be perfectly fine).

Comment: If you want to test EF then you need to create a mock context that will provide the appropriate implementation. I, however, like to unit test EF by creating throwaway databases, seed them, test them and then delete them as part of the unit test. It is a thin line between unit and integration testing, especially when it comes to ORM. In the end, you should choose to implement what meets your needs. If you need to know if AddAsync will work on the database level, then write a test that does that.